# how to start the animation if the storyboard definition and the corresponding grid inside canvas is in windows.resources tag

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

i want to start animation in the grid.the grid is inside the canvas tag.both the story board definition and the grid to animate is inside the windows.resources tag.
the code is given below

```
    <VisualBrush  x:Key="Passport" x:Shared="false" Stretch="Uniform">

        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  >
              <Grid Margin="5.397,45.106,5.239,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="7.801"   x:Name="side_scan_strip" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform >

                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
              </Grid>
               </Canvas>

        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>


        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames x:Name="dak1" BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName=" side_scan_strip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="109.75"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="109.75"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
```

the exception i got is :
' side_scan_strip' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow'.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of a little error :) In the Storyboard you have written: " side_scan_strip" while it should be "side_scan_strip". See the little space in the beginning of the first? I think that is what is triggering the exception.